# get notified when igx-grid has done loading

Tags: angular, infragistics, ignite-ui, ignite-ui-angular, igx-grid

I am trying to move a dynamic column to different position using Infragistics Angular grid, igx-grid.  I tried with

```js
const newCol = this.grid.getColumnByName(node);
newCol?.move(j);
```

but newCol is null since grid has not finished loading and new dynamic column has not been applied.
So I need to do this after grid is done loading.  What event can I subscribe to get this done?  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use [rendered](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/classes/igxgridcomponent.html#rendered) event emitter which is emitted after the ngAfterViewInit hook. At this point, the grid exists in the DOM. [StackBlitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-rendered-emitter?file=src/app/grid/grid-editing-sample/grid-editing-sample.component.ts) and [official igxGrid topic](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/grid).

```html
<igx-grid #grid1 [data]="data" [paging]="true" [primaryKey]="'ProductID'"
       (rendered)="rendered()">
```

Comment: nice, I will try this out.  Thanks

Comment: it's done rendering but data are not done loading so it still can't find the column to move